# TO-220 MOSFET (or SS relay) for 24VDC with 0V turn on voltage

Tags: mosfet

I am in need of a MOSFET (or solid state relay) in a TO-220 package that will switch 24 VDC high side to an inductive load (up to 2 amps) when 0VDC is applied to the gate.

I don't even know where to begin to look for such a solution. Any suggestions on specific components or how to proceed will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Edit: I would like to do it with zero other components, if possible. I have limited space on the PCB to include other components.

I am currently using a BTS462T as a switch but that requires 5VDC to turn on. I am looking for a solution that will turn on the 24VDC with a low.

Would depletion mode or enhancement mode be best in this situation?

Comment: This is pretty straightforward, unless you mean you want to do it with zero other components. What have you already tried, and why didn't that work?

Comment: just find a P-Chan with a Vgs(max) of more than 24 (or less than -24 depending on the datasheet)  and other params as needed.

Comment: What voltage will be applied to **turn off** the load?

Comment: I want the load to turn off at 5VDC. The signal is coming from a Velocio Ace 22 PLC which has outputs that are active low. Thus, when I turn on an output, it will go low and then turn on the MOSFET or solid state relay.

Comment: Why does it have to be in a TO-220 package?

Comment: Because that is the size of the component I am replacing. Other package styles would be acceptable if they take up the same amount of PCB space.

Answer (score 1):

You won't find a PMOSFET that you can use as a high-side switch and turn the switch off (non-conducting) with 5V on the gate and 24V on the source, then turn it on with 0V on the gate and 24V on the source. That's not how MOSFETs work.

You could combine a PMOSFET with a few other components, but it won't fit in a TO-220 package.

Answer (score 0):

Without more information about the driving circuit and the load, this is a guess.

Almost any p-channel power MOSFET with adequate ratings can act as the switch, with two small additional components - one resistor go guarantee turn-off when the driving signal goes open-circuit, and one zener diode to protect the gate from over-voltage.  The zener can be anything in the 6.2 V - 12 V range, and the resistor can be something in the 10K range.

Comment: The output of the PLC is pulled high so I assume that means I don't need an external resistor to pull the gate high. I was hoping to find a MOSFET that has a built in bypass diode. I "think" I've seen them elsewhere.

Comment: @MarqTwine, they do exist, but getting one that is p-channel, with 24-V Vgs, and 2 A current handling, in a TO-220 may not be possible.

Comment: "The output of the PLC is pulled high" - pulled high to what voltage?

Comment: The output of the PLC is pulled high to 5 VDC. I would like the output of the MOSFET or switch to be low under this condition. I think what I may want is an inverting IC switch.

Comment: The gate has to be pulled up to the source voltage to assure turn-off.  This can be done with an open collector / open drain transistor.  2N7000 / 2N7002

Answer (score 0):

I have learned that I can pull the output of the PLC high to 24VDC even though the PLC operates at 5VDC. So, I believe I can pull the gate of the MOSFET high for an off condition on the PLC. And, when I want to turn on the load, I can turn on the output of the PLC thus bringing the PLC output low and turning on the high side P channel MOSFET.

Confirmation of this scheme is invited. Thank you for all your help.